# Apply a confirmation alert box with all the users selected data

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, alert, confirmation

This is what I have but I seem to be hitting a wall. I have tried and re-tried different formulas but cant seen to get it. What I am trying to do is have the user answer the questions then when they hit 'confirm' all the data entered is relayed back to them as an 'alert'. help.
This is what I have:

--------------EDIT-------------

```
<head>
    <title>a4_part3</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        function storytime()
        { 
            //displays alert
            alert("Welcome to an Interactive Story Spot.");
        }

        function confirm()
        {   
            var spaceship = document.getElementsByName("transport")[0].value;
            var ducatti = document.getElementsByName("transport")[1].value;
            var ferrari = document.getElementsByName("transport")[2].value;
            var jet = document.getElementsByName("transport")[3].value;
            var train = document.getElementsByName("transport")[4].value;
            var transport = "";

            var name = document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value
            var title = document.getElementsByName("title")[0].value
            var noun = document.getElementsByName("noun")[0].value
            var num1 = document.getElementsByName("num1")[0].value
            var num2 = document.getElementsByName("num2")[0].value

            var miles = document.getElementsByName("measuretravel")[0].value
            var km=document.getElementsByName("measuretravel")[1].value;
            var travelmeasure = document.getElementsByName("measureravel").value


            //determine which mode of transportation was chosen
            if (document.getElementsByName("transport")[0].checked)
            {
                transport = spaceship;
            }
            else if (document.getElementsByName("transport")[1].checked)
            {
                transport = ducatti;
            }
            else if (document.getElementsByName("transport")[2].checked)
            {
                transport = ferrari;
            }
            else if (document.getElementsByName("transport")[3].checked)
            {
                transport = jet;
            }
            else if (document.getElementsByName("transport")[4].checked)
            {
                transport = train;
            }


            //determine which measure of travel was chosen
            if (document.getElementsByName("measuretravel")[0].checked)
            {
                miles = "+num1+" + "+num2+" * 1.60934
                measuretravel = miles;
            }
            else if (document.getElementsByName("measuretravel")[1].checked)
            {
                km = "+num1+" + "+num2+"
                measuretravel = km;
            }

            //display alert
            alert ("Hello, "+name+", your story values are "+title+", "+noun+", "+transport+", "num1", "num2", and "+measuretravel+" ");

        }

    //]]>
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <form id="storyform" action="">
        <h1>Create Your Own Story</h1>


        <p style="font-weight:bold;"> Your Name
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Jane Doe">  
        </p>            

        <p style="font-weight:bold;"> Story Title
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="Enter Story Title Here">  
        </p>

        <p style="font-weight:bold;">Choose A Mode Of TRANSPORTATION</p>

            <input type="radio" name="transport" id="transport" value="spaceship" checked="checked"> Spaceship
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="transport" id="transort1" value="ducati"> Ducati
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="transport" id="transport2" value="ferrari"> Ferrari
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="transport" id="transport3" value="jet"> Jet
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="transport" id="transport4" value="train"> Train

            <br>
            <br>

            Enter a NOUN <input type="text" name="noun" id="noun" value="Paris" onclick=""/>
                <br>
            Enter a NUMBER <input type="text" name="Num1" id="num1" value="1" checked="checked" onclick=""/> 
                <br>
            Enter Another NUMBER <input type="text" name="Num2" id="num2" value="2" onclick=""/> 

            <p style="font-weight:bold;">Choose a means of MEASURING TRAVEL</p>

            <input type="radio" name="measuretravel" id="measuretravel1" value="miles"> Miles
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="measuretravel" id="measuretravel2" value="km" checked="checked"> Kilometers


                <br>
                <br>
                <br>

            <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">

            <input type="button" value="Story Time!" onclick="storytime();">

            <input type="button" value="Confirm" onclick= "confirm();">


    </form>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two JS issues in this code. The first:

alert ("Hello, "+name+", your story values are "+title+", "+noun+", "+tansport+", "+num1+", "+num2+", and "+measuretravel+" ");

Should be

alert ("Hello, "+name+", your story values are "+title+", "+noun+", "+**transport**+", "+num1+", "+num2+", and "+measuretravel+" ");

The second is your `body onload="runJS()`, where runJS is not a defined function, but perhaps that's code that you didn't paste into the ticket.

Anyway fixing that first issues causes the popup to show.

Be sure to look in your development console for any javascript errors if you have code that doesn't seem to want to run.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about the onload.

Comment: In the code you posted, the function that you have specified to be called once the page is loaded, runJS, does not exist. This is causing an error to be thrown, though it should not impact the rest of the page's functionality. Look at your body tag.

Comment: I would think so, yes, if you didn't explicitly put it in there in the first place.

Comment: Excellent.
So in the alert box not all the users answers were popping up so I tweaked my code to:

var name = document.getElementByName("name").value
var title = document.getElementByName("title").value
var noun = document.getElementByName("noun").value
var num1 = document.getElementByName("num1").value
var num2 = document.getElementByName("num2").value

Something is wrong though...help

Comment: getElementByName is not a function that you can use. I found that pretty easily by saving this code to an html file, opening the html file, and watching developer tools when I clicked the confirm button.

Try using getElementsByName like you did with the "transport"

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: Try this: `var noun=document.getElementsByName("noun")[0].value

Comment: alert says "undefined"

Comment: Please update your question to indicate the code that you are now using, so I can have a better idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: In your DOM, you have an input named "Num1" and another named "Num2", but in the JavaScript, you are referring to them as "num1" and "num2". Reconcile the different names and you shouldn't have a problem anymore.

Comment: Yes it is working! Thank you.
However I have found another flaw here:

km = "+num1+" + "+num2+"

Comment: You want it to be km = num1 + " + " + num2. Notice the variables are outside the quotes-if you leave them inside the quotes, the name of the variable gets added to the string, rather then the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Lots and lots of basic syntax error and basic nomenclature errors.
I suggest you start using a particular nomenclature for your variables, 
and also use a lot of the Firebug Console / Chrome Developer Tools' Console to check your JS errors that come up! :)

Use this:

```
    <head>
    <title>a4_part3</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        function storytime()
        { 
            //displays alert
            alert("Welcome to an Interactive Story Spot.");
        }

        function confirm()
        {   
            var spaceship = document.getElementsByName("transport")[0].value;
            var ducatti = document.getElementsByName("transport")[1].value;
            var ferrari = document.getElementsByName("transport")[2].value;
            var jet = document.getElementsByName("transport")[3].value;
            var train = document.getElementsByName("transport")[4].value;
            var transport = "";

            var name = document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value
            var title = document.getElementsByName("title")[0].value
            var noun = document.getElementsByName("noun")[0].value
            var num1 = document.getElementsByName("num1")[0].value
            var num2 = document.getElementsByName("num2")[0].value

            var miles = document.getElementsByName("measuretravel")[0].value
            var km=document.getElementsByName("measuretravel")[1].value;
            var travelmeasure = document.getElementsByName("measureravel").value


            //determine which mode of transportation was chosen
            if (document.getElementsByName("transport")[0].checked)
            {
                transport = spaceship;
            }
            else if (document.getElementsByName("transport")[1].checked)
            {
                transport = ducatti;
            }
            else if (document.getElementsByName("transport")[2].checked)
            {
                transport = ferrari;
            }
            else if (document.getElementsByName("transport")[3].checked)
            {
                transport = jet;
            }
            else if (document.getElementsByName("transport")[4].checked)
            {
                transport = train;
            }


            //determine which measure of travel was chosen
            if (document.getElementsByName("measuretravel")[0].checked)
            {
                miles = "+num1+" + "+num2+" * 1.60934
                measuretravel = miles;
            }
            else if (document.getElementsByName("measuretravel")[1].checked)
            {
                km = "+num1+" + "+num2+"
                measuretravel = km;
            }

            //display alert
            alert ("Hello, "+name+", your story values are "+title+", "+noun+", "+transport+", "+num1+", "+num2+", and "+measuretravel+" ");

        }

    //]]>
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <form id="storyform" action="">
        <h1>Create Your Own Story</h1>


        <p style="font-weight:bold;"> Your Name
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Jane Doe">  
        </p>            

        <p style="font-weight:bold;"> Story Title
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="Enter Story Title Here">  
        </p>

        <p style="font-weight:bold;">Choose A Mode Of TRANSPORTATION</p>

            <input type="radio" name="transport" id="transport" value="spaceship" checked="checked"> Spaceship
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="transport" id="transort1" value="ducati"> Ducati
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="transport" id="transport2" value="ferrari"> Ferrari
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="transport" id="transport3" value="jet"> Jet
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="transport" id="transport4" value="train"> Train

            <br>
            <br>

            Enter a NOUN <input type="text" name="noun" id="noun" value="Paris" onclick=""/>
                <br>
            Enter a NUMBER <input type="text" name="num1" id="num1" value="1" checked="checked" onclick=""/> 
                <br>
            Enter Another NUMBER <input type="text" name="num2" id="num2" value="2" onclick=""/> 

            <p style="font-weight:bold;">Choose a means of MEASURING TRAVEL</p>

            <input type="radio" name="measuretravel" id="measuretravel1" value="miles"> Miles
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="measuretravel" id="measuretravel2" value="km" checked="checked"> Kilometers


                <br>
                <br>
                <br>

            <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">

            <input type="button" value="Story Time!" onclick="storytime();">

            <input type="button" value="Confirm" onclick= "confirm();">


    </form>


</body>
```

Happy Coding